# Solve $\int(1+\frac{1}{x})^{2}\frac{dx}{x^2}$

Tags: integration, derivatives

This seems to be a straightforward integral: 
$$\int(1+\frac{1}{x})^{2}\frac{dx}{x^2}$$

By substitution substitution, $u = 1+\frac{1}{x}, du = -\frac{1}{x^2}$

$$-\int u^2= -\frac{u^3}{3}+C = -\frac{(1+\frac{1}{x})^3}{3}$$

Then I took the derivative:

$$\frac{d}{dx}-\frac{(1+\frac{1}{x})^3}{3} = -\frac{1}{3}\frac{d}{dx}(1+\frac{1}{x})^3$$

If $u = 1+ \frac{1}{x}$  then $$-\frac{1}{3}\frac{d}{du}u^3 = -u^2 = -(1+\frac{1}{x})^2$$

What went wrong with my substitution?

Comment: You are taking the derivative with respect to $u$ and with respect to $x$ and getting them mixed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assumed $u=1+\dfrac 1x$. So far so good.

But you didn't replace $dx$ by $du$ correctly.

You must not forget that $du= -\dfrac 1{x^2} dx$

So,

$$\frac{d(1+\dfrac 1x)^3}{dx} = \frac{d(u^3)}{du} \color{red}{\cdot \frac{du}{dx}}$$

Always remember that

$$\color{blue}{\frac{d}{dx} f(x)= \frac{d}{du} f(x) \cdot \frac {du}{dx}}$$